# Return (redirect) to form on error

Tags: django, forms, redirect

I have two views /home and /home/addItem

/home contains a form for creating new items, and POSTs the data to /home/addItem, if the data validates addItem redirects the user back to /home, the trouble happens if the data doesn't validate:

I still want the user to go back to the form on /home, but I would like the form to contain the entered form-data along with the form errors notifying the user of what to fix.

most places, I have been able to find, suggest:

```
def addItem(request):
    form = NewItemForm(request.POST)
    if(form.is_valid()):
         #do stuff
         return HttpResponseRedirect("/home")
    return render_to_response("home-template.htm", {'form':form})
```

however, this solution will leave the user on /home/addItem while displaying the /home content, which will not work well in my case.

So how can I send the user to /home along with the form content and errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your form data is not big, may be you can store the submitted data in session/cookie and redirect user to `/home`. View for `/home` can check the session/cookie for any form data present and show the user a form with previously submitted data and any errors.

Sample code (check for errors, best methods to store/delete cookies):

```
def addItem(request):
    form = NewItemForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       #OK
       return HttpResponseRedirect("/home")
    else:
       request.session['form_data'] = request.POST #this may not be exact way, please verify.
       return HttpResponseRedirect("/home")

 def home(request):
    form_data = request.session.get('form_data', None)
    form = NewItemForm(initial=form_data)
    form.is_valid() # to get errors in form
    #render form using template.
```